# Move customer order notes field in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi all i have managed by searching and finding solutions to make a few edits to my checkout on woocommerce.

So far i have made it so i skip the cart/basket and go straight to checkout and have renamed the order notes filed. with the functions code below.

What i am struggling with is how to move the order notes field above the order review. I know i would need to use this woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review but i am not sure how. Any help would be great?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'themeprefix_add_to_cart_redirect');
function themeprefix_add_to_cart_redirect() {
 global $woocommerce;
 $checkout_url = wc_get_checkout_url();
 return $checkout_url;
}

//Add New Pay Button Text
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'themeprefix_cart_button_text' ); 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'themeprefix_cart_button_text' ); 

function themeprefix_cart_button_text() {
 return __( 'Add to cart & go to checkout', 'woocommerce' );
}

// Place this code in your theme's functions.php file

// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['order']['order_comments']['required'] = true;
     return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'filter_checkout_fields' );

function filter_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['maxlength'] = 160;
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = '<h2>Personalized Message</h2>';
     $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'Add message here';
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Order notes are not removable through hooks because they are located in Woocommerce template `checkout/form-shipping.php` … So you should need to [override Woocommerce templates via your active theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) removing an entire block of code from `checkout/form-shipping.php` to `checkout/review-order.php`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LoicTheAztec is correct. Order notes are only customizable through adjustment of Woocommerce templates.

On mutliple sites I had to remove and add the following code from and to the correct templates. This is from the default Woocommerce 3.x template.

```
<?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_enable_order_notes_field', 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_order_comments', 'yes' ) ) ) : ?>

    <?php if ( ! WC()->cart->needs_shipping() || wc_ship_to_billing_address_only() ) : ?>

        <h3><?php _e( 'Additional information', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="woocommerce-additional-fields__field-wrapper">
        <?php foreach ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'order' ) as $key => $field ) : ?>
            <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have just done the template override and found and moved this code. Which has moved it to where i want BUT i now have duplicates. As in i have two order notes fields.

Comment: Override the old template which contain this code and remove the code in the override. It should be working as the note field is only generated by this code.

Comment: I think i did. I copied both checkout/form-shipping.php and checkout/review-order.php to /wp-content/themes/mytheme/woocommerce/checkout/ then i removed the above code from shipping and added it to review. The field then displays in the correct place on my site but i have two of the same field.

Comment: Please double check the form-shipping.php in the childtheme override. Maybe add some additional HTML to make sure it is being used. If the additional html is not showing up there is some other template being used.

Comment: Just checked and the override is being used. [link](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3302268/d5fe1d00b92172ce7ebae9b96cdff0a6)

Comment: Ok have been having a play with this and it seems i can add this code to the form-checkout template and works without duplicating the field so am going to override that template instead.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if you feel it helped you. Ps i added the code to payment template.